# Simplify : find if element is in tuples stored in list

Tags: python

Is there a way to simplify this script using `in` keyword or anything like this:

```py
searched_value = 3
data = [("a", 1), ("b",2), ("c",3)]

### can be simplified ?
test = None
for i in data:
    if i[1] == searched_value:
        test = i[0]
        break
###

print(test)
```

Comment: Is this your entire program? If not, you need to show it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there is, except maybe unpacking the pairs:

```
test = None
for k, v in data:
    if v == searched_value:
        test = k
        break
```

You could use `next`, but I wouldn't call it simpler:

```
test = next((k for k, v in data if v == searched_value), None)
```